# Show result of pgAgent step

Tags: postgresql, pgagent

How setup pgAgent step so `Result` or `Output` show the number of rows processed on my function?

[image]

my function already return the number of rows affected, but that isnt the value show in `Result`.

```
BEGIN   
    WHILE  int_pending > 0  LOOP    
        .....  
        UPDATE table SET ....   
        GET DIAGNOSTICS int_row_count = ROW_COUNT;
        int_total = int_total + int_row_count;    
    END LOOP;

    RETURN int_total;           
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [source code of pgagent](https://github.com/postgres/pgagent/blob/master/job.cpp#L143) :

```
output = stepConn->GetLastError();

...

rc = threadConn->ExecuteVoid(
         wxT("UPDATE pgagent.pga_jobsteplog ")
         wxT("   SET jslduration = now() - jslstart, ")
         wxT("       jslresult = ") + NumToStr(rc) + wxT(", jslstatus = '") + stepstatus + wxT("', ")
         wxT("       jsloutput = ") + threadConn->qtDbString(output) + wxT(" ")
         wxT(" WHERE jslid=") + jslid);
```

pgagent stores last error of of job step execution.

So, there are two ways to implement desired behaviour:

- patch source code to implement your feature, recompile, install and use this custom version
- use `RAISE EXCEPTION` inside plpgsql function, something like this:

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_output() RETURNS VOID AS $$
     DECLARE
       rows int := 25;
     BEGIN
       RAISE EXCEPTION 'Updated rows: %', rows;
     END;
  $$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
  ```